# Overlap of pages whilst using \includepdf

Tags: pdfpages

I am trying to use the `pdfpages` package to include a PDF file called "`supp.pdf`". My code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,prl,aps,showpacs,twocolumn,unsortedaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{hyperref}                                       
\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{graphicx,bm}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

*Text*

\newpage
\newpage
\includepdf[pages=-,scale=1]{supp.pdf}
\end{document}
```

But if I compile, the first two pages of `supp.pdf` overlap  in the total file, that is, the two pages are printed on one page.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Hello! You compile with `pdflatex`, right?

Comment: @tohecz Yes, indeed.

Comment: What happens if you load the `hyperref` package *last* ? (It's currently being loaded first.) You probably don't need to load the `epsfig` package, and the `graphicx` package need only be loaded once, by the way.

Comment: @Mico I tried, but the pages still overlap.

Comment: How large are the pages of the PDF you are including? I notice you are using `scale=1` which suggests they don't match the pagesize of the document you are compiling. Also, how many pages are there? Do later pages work OK? Does the same thing happen with another PDF e.g. `l2tabuen.pdf` for example? (Don't ask me why that one. No idea.)

Comment: @cfr I only used the scale option because I thought this might resolve the problem, without it the first two pages still overlap. The document I am including is of exactly the same style in which I am including it. Indeed, the later pages do include OK. With other pdf files the same thing happens. I have the feeling it has something to do with the fact that the first page of supp.pdf has no page number: the numbering starts at page two with the number two. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve my problem artificially by writing

```
\includepdf[pages={1,{},2-5}]{supp.pdf}
```

The "{}" means I insert an empty page by hand. I still think it's weird that Latex doesn't do this correctly on its own, but this method works.

Answer (score 2):

even simpler
`\includepdf[pages={{},-}]{supp.pdf}`

Comment: Providing a full minimal working example or explaining a bit more about how this answer solves the problem would be great. Also, a tip: you can mark inline code with backticks (`\``), as I did in my edit. You can also mark code blocks by starting a line with four spaces. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted. Works for me in solving a similar problem