# pdfpage and Lyx, avoid superpositions of pages

Tags: lyx, pdfpages

When I include a pdf-document inside a `Lyx` document using the function inside `Lyx` (Insert -> External Material) which calls `pdfpages`, at least two pages are super-impressed (one appear on top of an other one), it is either (suppose I put the pdf-document at the end of my typing)

- the last page of the `Lyx` document and the first page of the pdf-document
- the two-first pages of the pdf document, when I try to put a clear-page, page-break or new-page in Lyx in order to avoid the first problem

Is there a way to avoid this ? Is it material dependent, or a problem with my options in `pdfpages` (I just put `pages=-`, `fitpaper=true`) ?

I'm using `revtex 4-1`, is it possible it's a conflict between templates ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try \usepackage{pdfpages}?

Comment: @George LyX adds that for you, and without it  an error would be issued when creating the PDF.

Comment: Have you tried adding a page break before the external material?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for your comment. I tried to put a page-break, new-page and clear-page. They all result in a superposition of the two first pages of the extra pdf-document.

Comment: Seems `revtex` is incompatible with `pdfpages`. There is a possible workaround in [Inserting a PDF file in REVTeX 4.1 with reprint option](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227385) (requires ERTs). Alternatively, you could generate the document without the included PDF, and merge the two PDFs afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
As said  Torbjørn T., it was a problem of incompatibility with `revtex` for me.
I did a work around by adding an empty page at the start of my included pdf with the following code:

```
~ % unbreakable space
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\newpage
```