# LaTeX /includepdf stacks images on top of eachother

Tags: graphics, pdfpages

I'm trying to insert a pdf with multiple images into my LaTeX document using `\includepdf` but either no image shows up (for `page={1}` or `page={1-4}` etc.) or it stacks them all on top of each other and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I've been using `\includegraphics` for other images (pdf and png) but for files like this, where there are 40+ images (one per page) in a single pdf file I can't use the **`graphics`** package but **`pdfpages`** doesn't seem to be working either. I'm using Sublime to compile on a Mac.

Here is the preamble I have (which is mostly copied from a astronomy paper example):

```
\documentclass[iop,revtex4,twocolappendix]{emulateapj}   
\usepackage{natbib}  
\usepackage{epsfig}  
\usepackage{lscape}  
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x2,column=true,columnstrict=true,lastpage=36]{XDGNIRS_v20.pdf}
\end{document}
```

This creates something similar to the following image. I can't take a picture of my real file since it's unpublished data and my mentor would be not be happy. But I think it's clear that pages are over-plotting and creating ugly. (Multiple pages are created that all look similar to this jibberish.)

[image: Example messed up image]

Ideally this is in a picture environment such that I can add a title, caption, and reference. I want a "picture array" which `nup` does do, but maybe using that, the images can't be transferred over multiple pages which is why it just plots the images on top of each other? Except, it's the first three images that are stacked on top of each other and then the next three for the second image in the `nup` array, and so on. I'm pretty new to LaTeX so I'm confuddled.

Comment: Welcome! Note that you can format code blocks by highlighting and hitting `ctrl+k` or the `{}` button. Could you post a complete small document which demonstrates the problem? You could use a standard PDF (like a manual) in place of your file. It is easier to help if people can see exactly what is going on by reproducing the problem. `pdfpages` does not normally behave as you describe.

Comment: Edited. Is that what you meant? I ran just those small blocks of code all on their own and it does the same thing as in my larger document (which has a bunch of sections/subsections/pictures etc.). The image is just of a manual I have, but it should be the same for any multiple-page pdf file.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. That's crucial information. If I use `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pdfpages}\begin{document}...` it works just fine. So the rest is needed to reproduce the problem. I've just made it into a single code block as it is easier for people to copy-paste that way.

Comment: Don't use `epsfig`. It is obsolete. The only package your example actually needs is `pdfpages`. I can reproduce the problem with just that and the class....

Comment: \documentclass[iop,revtex4,twocolappendix]{emulateapj}

Comment: `\documentclass[iop,revtex4,twocolappendix]{emulateapj}` is used for astronomy papers. It creates the default style for submitting to journals like APJ and AAS. But that is where the problem is... Is there another forum like this for astronomers? I know there is some way to create a similar image using that document class. (I don't know what happened with above comment, sorry.) Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Not that I know of. I just meant that it was good you added that to the question because it is important you are using that class. If we don't know that, we can't reproduce the problem. Once we know you are using that class, we can. Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227385/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-revtex-4-1-with-reprint-option help? The basic problem is that the class uses `revtex4` which is incompatible with a lot of packages, including `pdfpages`, it seems. Basically, an answer there suggests including the pages using a loop rather than `pdfpages` multi-page commands.

Comment: You can loop through the pages without `pgffor` using something like `\newcounter{mylooppages}
\setcounter{mylooppages}{0}
\newcommand*\mylooppages[2]{%
  \includepdf[pages=#1]{#2}}
\newcommand*\myloop[3]{%
  \ifnum0=\value{mylooppages}%
 \setcounter{mylooppages}{#1}%
 \mylooppages{\themylooppages}{#3}%
  \fi
  \stepcounter{mylooppages}%
  \ifnum#2<\value{mylooppages}%
 \setcounter{mylooppages}{0}%
  \else
 \mylooppages{\themylooppages}{#3}%
 \myloop\themylooppages{#2}{#3}%
  \fi}` but you lose the ability to include multiple images per page.