# Including pdfpages renders rotated RevTeX 4.1 pdfLaTex output

Tags: pdfpages, revtex, arxiv

This happened when I updated `MikTeX` to the latest version (as of time of this post) and tried the [workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160008/62063) regarding adding pdf pages to `RevTeX` documents. Running the code below produced text rotated by 90 degrees while commenting out the line which includes the `pdfpages` packages produces regularly positioned text. Note that the page number was not rotated. **Can anyone reproduce this and what is the cause of this?**

```
\documentclass[english]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{pdfpages}  % Including PDF 
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{revtex4-1}\usepackage{pdfpages}\useepackage{blindtext}\begin{document}\blindtext\end{document}` would be enough as an MWE. As you have written in another post, the maintainers of `revtex4-1` do not provide compatiblity to `pdfpages`. Anyhow, I put a bounty here, as Dennis is issueing the same problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The  same happen with

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1} 
\usepackage{lscape}    

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\end{document}
```

because `revtex4-1` redefine the output routine: `\@outputpage` we need to don't rotate the  outputbox. A quick fix is

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}     
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\LS@rot\@undefined}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\end{document}
```

**Edit** With the help of `etoolbox` package if we really need to use `lscape` we can do

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@outputpage@head}{\@ifx{\LS@rot\@undefined}{}{\LS@rot}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\end{document}
```