# Latex Compiling to Landscape

Tags: miktex, texlive

I have the following code

```
%% ****** Start of file rsitemplate.tex ****** %
%%
%%   This file has been edited from the original source file.
%%   The original file is part of the revtex4-1 package indicated below.
%%   Version 4.1 of 9 October 2009.
%%
%
% This is a template for producing documents for use with 
% the REVTEX 4.1 document class and the RSI substyle.
% 
% Copy this file to another name and then work on that file.
% That way, you always have this original template file to use.

\documentclass[aip, apl, amsmath, amssymb, reprint, onecolumn, twoside]{revtex4-1} % for checking your page length
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[section]{placeins} % Para que los flotantes queden en la sección 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}} % Para que las tablas se numeren en arabigos

%==============================================
% To include pdf + LaTeX figures
%=============================================

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{transparent}

\newcommand{\incfig}[2][1]{%
    \def\svgwidth{#1\textwidth}
    \import{./images/}{#2.pdf_tex}
}


%==============================================

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% \frontmatter@RRAP@format is responsible for the parentheses
\patchcmd{\frontmatter@RRAP@format}{(}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\frontmatter@RRAP@format}{)}{}{}{}
\renewcommand\Dated@name{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


    \title{Medición del período de oscilación de un péndulo por varios métodos.} 

    \author{Michel \surname{Romero Rodríguez}\\\vspace{1mm} \emph{Instituto Balseiro. Comisión Nacional de Energía Atómica.\\\vspace{1mm}michel.romero@ib.edu.ar}}
    %\email[]{ michel.romero@ib.edu.ar}

    %\affiliation{Instituto Balseiro. Comisión Nacional de Energía Atómica.\\michel.romero@ib.edu.ar}


    \begin{abstract}
    \rightskip.5in
        Se midió el período de las oscilaciones de un péndulo simple por varios métodos. Se realizaron diferentes análisis estadísticos con las mediciones y se concluyó que el valor medio no varía con el método empleado para procesar los datos pero sí el valor de las desviaciones estándar. Resultó no ser tan importante el número de mediciones independientes realizadas como la cantidad de períodos medidos en cada una de ellas.
    \end{abstract}

    \date{\today}

    \maketitle 

    %===============================================
    %Begin section Intriducción
    %===============================================

    \section{Introducción} 
    \label{sec:intro}

        El péndulo simple es un modelo que consiste en una masa puntual atada a una cuerda o varilla imponderable e inextensible. Para el caso de pequeñas oscilaciones respecto a su posición de equilibrio, el período $T$ de estas oscilaciones depende solamente de la aceleración de la gravedad $g$ y la longitud de la cuerda $l$ según la ecuación

        \begin{equation}
            \label{eq:T}
            T = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}.
        \end{equation}

        En este trabajo se medió el período de las oscilaciones de un péndulo simple a través de diferentes métodos con el objetivo de comparar los resultados por cada uno de ellos. Se emplearon varios métodos para analizar los resultados para comprobar cuál es más útil. En la sección \ref{sec:met} se explican los métodos seguidos en las mediciones y en la sección \ref{sec:res_disc} se discuten los resultados obtenidos.

    %===============================================
    %End section Intriducción
    %===============================================



    %===============================================
    %Begin section Métodos y materiales
    %===============================================

    \section{Métodos y materiales} 
    \label{sec:met}

    Se midió el período de las oscilaciones del péndulo de las siguientes formas:
    \begin{enumerate}[1., leftmargin=4\parindent]       
        \item $100$ mediciones independientes de un período iniciadas desde la posición $1$ mostrada en la Figura \ref{fig:pend} que representa la posición de máximo alejamiento de la posición de equilibrio.
        \item $100$ mediciones independientes de un período iniciadas desde la posición $2$ mostrada en la Figura \ref{fig:pend} que representa la posición de equilibrio y de máxima velocidad del péndulo.
        \item $33$ mediciones independientes de 3 períodos cada una iniciadas desde la posición $2$.
        \item Una medición de un período, una medición de $2$ períodos, ... y  una medición de 10 períodos.
    \end{enumerate}


    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \incfig[.6]{drawing-1}
        \caption{Péndulo simple. Los puntos 1 y 2 fueron utilizados como comienzo de las mediciones.}
        \label{fig:pend}
    \end{figure}



    Para esto se utilizó un cronómetro digital con precisión hasta la centésima de segundo. También se midió la longitud de la cuerda del péndulo con una cinta métrica que mide hasta los milímetros para comprobar los resultados obtenidos con los que arroja la Ecuación \ref{eq:T}.

    %===============================================
    %End section Métodos y materiales
    %===============================================

    %===============================================
    %Begin section Resultados y discución
    %===============================================

    \section{Resultados y discusión} 
    \label{sec:res_disc}


        Las $100$ mediciones realizadas en los puntos 1 y 2 se muestran en la Figura \ref{fig:100med}. En ambos casos se ve cómo los histogramas se ajustan a una gaussiana, lo que pone de manifiesto la aleatoriedad de las mediciones.

        \begin{figure*}[h]
            \subfloat[Iniciando en el punto $1$. \label{subf:1}]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{images/1.pdf}}
            \hfill
            \subfloat[Iniciando en el punto $2$. \label{subf:2}]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{images/2.pdf}}
            \caption{Mediciones de 100 períodos independientes.}
            \label{fig:100med}
        \end{figure*}

        Con los valores del punto dos se hicieron luego dos análisis más, agrupando y promediando los valores para obtener una lista de 50 y 33 períodos respectivamente. En la Figura \ref{fig:alt} se muestran los histogramas obtenidos con estas nuevas mediciones. Como se aprecia en las figuras, la gaussiana del histograma en la Figura \ref{subf:d} es más estrecha que las demás, indicando que la desviación estándar de las mediciones en este caso es menor que en los anteriores.

        \begin{figure*}[h!] 
            \subfloat[Promedio de dos en dos. \label{subf:c}]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{images/c.pdf}}
            \hfill
            \subfloat[Promedio de tres en tres. \label{subf:d}]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{images/d.pdf}}
            \caption{Análisis alternativos de las mediciones obtenidas en el punto 2.}
            \label{fig:alt}
        \end{figure*}   

        Con los valores medidos en el punto 3 se obtuvieron los períodos de una sola oscilación dividiendo entre 3 cada uno de los tiempos medidos. Con estos valores se realizó el histograma que se muestra en la Figura \ref{fig:3}. Con las mediciones realizadas en el punto 4 se hizo un ajuste lineal (Figura \ref{fig:f}) por mínimos cuadrados en el que la pendiente representa el período de una sola oscilación del péndulo.

        \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
            \label{fig:e}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/e.pdf}
            \caption{Histograma con los períodos calculados de las mediciones del punto 3.}
            \label{fig:3}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/f.pdf}
            \caption{Ajuste lineal de las mediciones realizadas en el punto 4.}
            \label{fig:f}
        \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}


        Del ajuste lineal se obtiene que para el período de las oscilaciones del péndulo \[T_{\text{mc}} = (1.856 \pm 0.005)\, \text{s}\]

        En la Tabla \ref{tab:1} se muestran los resultados para los diferentes análisis de las mediciones. Primeramente se llega a la conclusión de que es mejor tomar el punto de comienzo 2, pues nos lleva a mediciones con menor desviación estándar, lo que supone una mayor precisión de las mediciones. No quiere esto decir que las mediciones por este método sean más exactas que por el métodos del punto 1, pues la exactitud también viene asociada con los errores sistemáticos de los que no se obtiene resultado alguno con el análisis estadístico.

        \begin{center}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
            \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|}
            \hline\hline
                Método, Análisis & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\overline{T}\ (\text{s})$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\sigma$\ (\text{s})} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\sigma_{\overline{T}}$\ (\text{s})}\\\hline\hline
                Método del punto 1, las 100 mediciones &  $1.8406$ & $0.0606500$ & $0.00606500$\\
                Método del punto 2, las 100 mediciones & $1.8506$ & $0.0352142$ & $0.00352142$\\
                Método del punto 2, promedios de 2 en 2 & $1.8506$ & $0.0267955$ & $0.00378946$\\
                Método del punto 2, promedios de 3 en 3 & $1.8503$ & $0.0236491$ & $0.00411678$\\
                Método del punto 3, los 33 períodos & $1.8601$ & $0.0132677$ & $0.00230961$\\
            \hline\hline
            \end{tabular}
            \captionof{table}{Resultados de los diferentes análisis realizados a las mediciones}
            \label{tab:1}
        \end{center}

        Para el caso de las mediciones realizadas desde el punto 2, se ve que el valor medio se mantiene igual en todas las formas de analizar las mediciones:

        \[
        \overline{x}_a  = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n/a} \left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^ax_j}{a}\right)}{n/a}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n/a} \sum_{j=1}^ax_j}{n}=\frac{ \sum_{k=1}^nx_k }{n}=\overline{x}.
        \]

        En realidad en la tabla se ve que el valor medio de los puntos promediados de 3 en 3 es diferente al de los otros dos, esto es porque hubo que descartar un valor de las mediciones, pues $100 = 3\times33 + 1$.

        La desviación estándar de las mediciones se hace menor mientras agrupamos las mediciones en promedios de ellas. Esto se ve en los histogramas, la gaussiana que se ajusta a ellos es más estrecha cuanto más agrupamos las mediciones. Sin embargo la desviación estándar del valor medio aumenta mientras agrupamos las mediciones. De modo que estos análisis alternativos no nos brindan ninguna mejora en la precisión del valor medio.

        El tercero de los métodos, en el que se medía el tiempo de tres períodos para con esto calcular el de uno solo, es el que mejores resultados muestra en cuanto a la precisión de las mediciones. Al compararlo con los resultados para las 100 mediciones del punto 2 se llega a la conclusión de que no es tan importante el número de mediciones independientes como la cantidad de oscilaciones que se miden en cada una.

        Se pudiera pensar que al ser también 33 mediciones y que cada una es el resultado buscar la media de tres oscilaciones, el resultado debería ser el mismo que el de los promedios de 3 en 3 de las mediciones del punto 2. Pero la diferencia está justificada: las 33 mediciones del tercer método fueron mediciones de tres períodos con la incertidumbre propia de una medición, mientras que los 33 valores calculados de las mediciones del punto 2 vienen cada una dada a partir tres mediciones independientes de un período con la misma incertidumbre cada una.

        El período calculado con la Ecuación \ref{eq:T} a partir de la longitud de la cuerda $L = (85.8 \pm 0.1)\, \text{cm}$ es \[T = (    1.859, 0.001)\, \text{s}\]

        Comparando con todos los resultados anteriores se ve que el más exacto es el método del punto 3, seguido de el método del punto 4.
        Es de esperar que los resultados sean más precisos y exactos si hacemos mediciones de un número grande de períodos, pues con cada uno disminuye la incertidumbre.

    %===============================================
    %End section Resultados y discución
    %===============================================


    %===============================================
    %Begin section Conclusiones
    %===============================================

    \section{Conclusiones} 
    \label{sec:concl}

        Se midió el período de las oscilaciones de un péndulo simple con cuatro métodos diferentes. Se calculó la media, la desviación estándar de las mediciones y la del valor medio para cada uno de los métodos. Para uno de ellos se agruparon las mediciones en promedios de a 2 y de a 3 y se llegó a la conclusión de que esto no afecta el valor medio de las medicines; sin embargo, disminuye la desviación estándar de las mediciones y aumenta la del valor medio.

        El método más exacto, resultó ser el método en que se medía el tiempo de tres períodos; seguido de la ajuste lineal por mínimos cuadrados. El número de mediciones independientes realizadas no resultó ser tan importante para el resultado como la cantidad de períodos medidos en cada una.


    %===============================================
    %End section Conclusiones
    %===============================================

    \vfill

%\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
% \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
% \bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{bib}



\pagebreak

%\begin{widetext}
%\section*{APÉNDICE I: SERIES DE FOURIER}
%
%
%\end{widetext}


\end{document}
%
% ****** End of file aiptemplate.tex ******
```

I'm compiling it on Linux, using the LaTeXTools plugin of Sublime Text 3 and it gives a pdf similar to the expected result but rotated counterclockwise. Compiling it on Windows with the same plugin but using MikTex gives the expected result. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please make sure your MWE is self contained, it refers to several pieces of graphics we do not have access to. It seems to be a known issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324963/3929

Comment: @daleif the answer to that question solved my issue. What does MWW mean?

Comment: MWE= Minimal Working Example, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/3929, basically you should always add code others can test (you did, good job), not just some sniplet with no document class or preamble. NBut the code should also not contain references to material we do not have access to like images, external files, commercial fonts.